# iPhone updating the UI Contents by a database is acceptable by APP store?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

My iPhone/iPad app will connect to a remote database and will download a zip file including images or an xml file defining some layouts.

I am not sure does Apple store allows us to download new UI content and update the app ourselfs, if someone can tell me which points below are acceptable and which are not, could be great!

```
 1-Changing the image of splash screen

 2-Changing the images of buttons(next, back, main menu..), navigation bar, navigation toolbar.

 3-Changing only the color of the buttons

 3-Changing the background image of UIviews.

 4-Changing the company logo in the navigation Bar.

 5-Changing the texts of the buttons.

 6-Changing the fonts and colors of texts.
```

For instance app can download a very bad button image which does not fix any where and texts should overflow the labels..etc. I'm changing view of the application to something different other than it is first accepted. You think it is risky to build this way or limit the users on to which extend they can modify the app

Also the content will always change but I dont think it is a problem.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing any of those (except a "splash screen" displayed using Default.png, which you cannot change as it is built into the app bundle) is not necessarily against the App Store guidelines, but of course the final decision is up to Apple. However,

1. Be sure the app continues to work acceptably if a download fails or a corrupt/truncated download is received.
2. Do not include "placeholder" text or images that can be viewed before any download is received.
3. Be sure there is no ambiguity in your description or review notes that might cause Apple to think the updates contain any sort of executable code.
4. Make sure that the downloads don't cause your app to violate any of Apple's various guidelines. Particularly trademark/copyright infringement or inappropriate content, and *especially* if you allow user-generated content to be downloaded (you may well have to moderate user-generated content).

Comment: tnx for instance app can download a very bad button image which does not fix any where and texts should overflow the labels..etc. I'm changing view of the application to something different other than it is first accepted. You thibk it is risky to build this way or limit the users on to which extend they can modify the app

Comment: I'd be curious to take a look at a before/after screenshot. What are you trying to achieve, going through the acceptance process and show some potentially unacceptable content after the app is validated? Remember Apple staff does not only run the code through its scripts to check for unauthorized API, they also run the actual app and look at what it's doing (and how it looks, in this case).

Comment: @Anomie tnx can you also check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6859398/apple-store-acceptance-submitting-an-app-which-users-other-services-for-profit

Answer (score 2):

One thing you can't change for sure is the splash screen, as the Default.png image is stored inside your app bundle, and no change is permitted therein.

Comment: Button images and navigation bar images?